# "require" not work in embeded lua

Tags: lua, lua-5.2

in this code i load and run `test.lua` file

```
int main (){
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

my test.lua file contents

```
print ("s1");
r=require 'simple';
print ("s2");
```

the `simple` module is installed before

when run `./lua_c` ; output is only: `s1`

but when run `lua test.lua`; output is

```
s1
s2
```

and `r` in't nil

Comment: Where is your `simple.lua` (or `simple.so`) located?

Comment: It's not finding 'simple', obviously. This is a question about your environment, not code.

Comment: @Egor: my lua version is 5.2 and i copy simple.so in all path : `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so;./?.so`

Comment: @Mud: why lua find it?!?!

Comment: Are permissions for .so-file set correctly?

Comment: yes! i set `simple.so` permission to 777

Comment: Check the return value of `luaL_dofile` and print the error message left at the top of the Lua stack if there is an error.

Comment: @lhf: `luaL_loadfile` return zero value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simple` is failing to load or parse or execute. To find problem, use `luaL_loadfile` instead of `luaL_dofile` and check the return value. If non zero, there was a load error, which you can pop off the Lua stack and print. If no error, do the `lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))` to run the chuck created by loadfile, and again check return code for error, pop off stack and print. It would be somehting like this:

```
int main ()
{
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua"))
    {
         cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << endl;
    }
    else if (lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
    {
         cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         // call successful
    }

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Update: now that you know from the error message that simple.so has undefined symbol: `lua_gettop`, you know that there is a link error. Perhaps `simple.so` isn't linked to `lua51.so`, but since it works from lua.exe, which is linked to lua lib, one would it would work from your app, which is surely linked to it too. Another possibility is that lua.exe is statically linked but simple.so is not linked. Verify that `simple.so` is linked to lua51.so and that the lib it links to can be found such as via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Verify lua.exe is linked to same .so.

Comment: `luaL_loadfile` return zero value

Comment: Ok, so loads fine; as described, then run the protected call and surely that one will return non-zero

Comment: but why `lua` can run  `require simple.so` without problem ? ,in my code i can load `simple.lua` but can't load `simple.so`

Comment: @ChiChak right now, it's anyone's guess. The error returned by pcall will tell you.

Comment: i write `lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))` after loadfile, and `lua_pcall` return `2` !

Comment: @ChiChak exactly, if it returns 2 it means there was an error. I have extended answer to show how to print it.

Comment: i give error : `‘luaL_tostring’ was not declared in this scope` ; after change `luaL_tostring` to `lua_tostring` i see `error: error loading module 'simple' from file './simple.so':
        ./simple.so: undefined symbol: lua_gettop`

Comment: thank you, in my program `lua.a` is compile statically ; i question about this error on lua IRC channel; and reply this anwser `cmtptr: link your app with -rdynamic to tell the linker to export lua's symbols so your lua module can find them` ; my problem was solved

Comment: @Babyy Ah, of course, it's been such a long time since I used static libs that I forgot that possibility. But now you know how to use loadfile and pcall to get diagnostics that help point to source of problem, good work!